# Extract EdgeList From Non-Square Matrix

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Given a non-square 3x10 matrix like below, is there a way to extract the implied EdgeList from it. For example, the Edgelist from the below matrix would be S1->F1, S1->F5,S1->F9, S2->F9,S3->F1,S3->F9

```
{
 {"", "F1", "F2", "F3", "F4", "F5", "F6", "F7", "F8", "F9", "F10"},
 {"S1", 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.},
 {"S2", 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.},
 {"S3", 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
A = {{"", "F1", "F2", "F3", "F4", "F5", "F6", "F7", "F8", "F9", 
    "F10"}, {"S1", 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.}, {"S2", 0.,
     0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.}, {"S3", 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
    0., 0., 0., 1., 0.}};
edges = SparseArray[A[[2 ;;, 2 ;;]]]["NonzeroPositions"];
```

> {{1, 1}, {1, 5}, {1, 9}, {2, 9}, {3, 1}, {3, 9}}

To obtain the correct vertex labels, we can do the follow:

```
{i, j} = Transpose[edges];
Thread[A[[i + 1, 1]] -> A[[1, j + 1]]]
```

> {"S1" -> "F1", "S1" -> "F5", "S1" -> "F9", "S2" -> "F9", "S3" -> "F1",
>     "S3" -> "F9"}

Comment: Henrik: Very clever!! ... Very much appreciate your help!! ... prg

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

This is what we call a bipartite incidence matrix.  [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM) supports these.

```
IGBipartiteIncidenceGraph[
 {mat[[2 ;;, 1]], mat[[1, 2 ;;]]}, (* vertex names *)
 Round@mat[[2 ;;, 2 ;;]], (* the matrix *)
 VertexLabels -> Automatic, 
 DirectedEdges -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you Szabolcs. I have just started working with IGraph/M. It is very impressive. Thank you for the help ... prg

Answer (score 1):

```
toEdgeList[m_] := m[[#, 1]] -> m[[1, #2]]& @@@ Position[m, 1.]
toEdgeList @ mat
```

> {"S1" -> "F1", "S1" -> "F5", "S1" -> "F9", "S2" -> "F9", "S3" -> "F1", "S3" -> "F9"}

Also

```
vList = Join[mat[[2 ;;, 1]], mat[[1, 2 ;;]]];
am = PadLeft[mat[[2 ;;, 2 ;;]], {-#, #} &@Length[vList]];
EdgeList[AdjacencyGraph[vList, am]]
```

> {"S1" -> "F1", "S1" -> "F5", "S1" -> "F9", "S2" -> "F9", "S3" -> "F1", "S3" -> "F9"}